# Excel VBA drop down box queryselection code doesn’t work to submit for update

Tags: vba

This line of code in my excel macro
    `IE.document.querySelector("option[value='4000']")`  doesn't work.
    What selection query code works for this site? 
https://www.corsicahockey.com/nhl/players/nhl-player-ratings-rankings.

The **HTML** website code is:

```
<div class="col"> 
    <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap justify-content-lg-end">
        <label class="d-none d-sm-inline-block">Show</label>
        <select id="filter_limits_select">
            <option value='10' >10</option>
            <option value='25'>25</option>
            <option value='50'>50</option>
            <option value='100'selected>100</option>
            <option value='200'>200</option>
            <option value='500'>500</option>
            <option value='4000' >All</option>
        </select>
```

I can properly select the change option `value = "4000"`. 
But the `ie.document.selection` query code does not submit for update.
 Do you have the correct code that will work for this website?

Comment: Please update your post to add the rest of your code - difficult to tell what the problem might be without knowing what you're doing.